# How to store array into multiple mysql rows?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

I want to generete a index of all image files in a folder and save this to mysql column "picID":

Get Files with scandir:

```
$images = scandir("./", 1);
// print_r($images);
```

Send Array to `MySQL` (into Column "picID") - but How?

In the End it should be sg. like this:

```
| id | picID      |   A N D  N O T :  | id | picID                    |
|----|------------|                   |----|--------------------------|
| 1  | DSC237.jpg |                   | 1  | DSC237.jpg, DSC947.jpg   |
| 2  | DSC947.jpg |                   | .. | ..                       |
```

Solution: I modified Patricks answer to achieve my goal:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db") or die(mysqli_error($link));
$images = "('" . implode( scandir("./", 1), "'),('") . "')";
// Result is: ('a'),('b'),('c') -> VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c')
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `tablename` (picID) VALUES $images");
```

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt and then show us what goes wrong with your code. Check the "related" sidebar on the right of this page for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($images as $img) {
    $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `table` (picID) VALUES ('$img')");
}
```

Even better, may need some tweaking:

```
function insertIntoDB($dir) {
    foreach(scandir($images) as $img) {
        if(is_dir($img)) {
            insertIntoDB($dir);
        } else {
            $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `table` (picID) VALUES ('$img')");
        }
    }
}
```

Better way of multiple inserts:

[Batch inserts with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936458/batch-inserts-with-php)

MySQLi Injection Info:

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Hey i get a "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in line 35 (Your 2nd line)

Comment: You need to modify that line depending on your MySQL method. (MySQL, MySQLi, PDO)

Comment: That is not right way. In general you should not loop over queries. It's better to build a mass insert and run it as one query. Also data arguments are not escaped making it vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @PatrickSavalle, more of a proof of concept to help him in the right direction. As there is little effort in his post I don't want to write his application for him.

Comment: Thank You Jono, i will try it your way, feedback comes later ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$images = "('" . implode( scandir("./", 1), "'),('") . "')";
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `table` (picID) VALUES $images");
```

Comment: when i echo $images it looks like: "001.jpg','002.jpg','003.jpg','..','." - ist this right? I get no errors but the mysql table is still empty

Comment: That is not right. It looks like '001.jpg','002.jpg','003.jpg','..','.' Which is correct. Don't know why the table is still empty.

Comment: hey patrick, your snippet stores all values from the array in one row in the col 'picID'. But how do i make it to save this array into multiple rows (@picID col)?

Comment: Aha, I see, mistake. I corrected the example. You could have just read the manual yourself instead of helplessly waiting for someone else to come to your aid ;) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html