# Inserting multiple rows in a database from 1 form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

Ok so i need to insert multiple rows into a database using MySql from one form, each row is a result. The was i started doing it is the following:

```
INSERT INTO results (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), (8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
```

And so on, my question is:

I don't know how many rows of results a user will want to insert ( a maximum of 15 will apply). Is their a more practical way of achieving the same result? Or am I better off sticking to the way i originally planned?

Comment: You can have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680494/insert-multiple-rows-with-pdo-prepared-statements/21653119#21653119 and read my answer

Comment: @JustinIurman Thanks, just read it. Cheers for the quick response!

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, the link i gave you is about inserting data with **one** query. Otherwise, you can use a loop with multiple inserts

Comment: @JustinIurman Im only inserting one row of results just each row will have different information that needs to be inserted into the database. But it will definitely help me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**1°) Use prepared statement (like in Java):**

(For safe code, always use prepared statement and avoid generate SQL)

```
$stmt =  $db->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO foo_table (id, firstname, lastname) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
foreach($myarray as $row)
{
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $row['id'], $row['firstname'], $row['lastname']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
```

To understant "iss" param in `bind_param`: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

**2°) Generate batch insert:**

[Batch inserts with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936458/batch-inserts-with-php)

Comment: Be aware that batch inserts are allowed only upto 1000 records at a time in mysql.