# Importing millions no of records from text file to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, large-data

I need to insert records in MYSQL from a text file, that's not a problem.

The problem is that the text file contains millions of record. This means that processing one text file would results into millions of INSERT query. Also I can't (don't want to) use PHP Infile as I have to perform some data extraction on the text file. Storing that file into a Blob field this is not what I am looking.

Comment: What do you mean 'I have to perform some data extraction?'. With the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE you can make various modifications to the columns (values) before inserting data. You can split field value into several parts, etc,etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of individual INSERTs use bulk INSERTs like

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,23),(2,34),(4,33);
```

Might be worth looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307618/multiple-mysql-insert-statements-in-one-query-php).

Keep in mind that you might hit the packet size limit, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes) for pointers.

Comment: What time it takes when i increase mysql Packet size ,,hav u an Idea  For 1 Millions Records. May be Bulk Insert In Chunks helps me.but i need a idea about What no of records i should insert in 1 query .

Comment: It depends on the content in the query, so figure out a rough estimate  based on a single record and go from there.

Comment: Thanx for your Reply ,I want to insert 3 fields (Ip &  Name & ) from 1 row in Text file ,,,,May be i sud chunk Insert Query Like This ,,Bulk Insert for 10000 records in a query & 10000 Query Like This ....