# Iterating through array and uploading data into rows in database

Tags: php, mysql, post, checkbox

I have a few checkboxes that i want to insert their values into a database if they are checked.

```
HTML:
<input type="checkbox" id="m1" name="category[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="m2" name="category[]" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="m3" name="category[]" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="m4" name="category[]" value="4"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="m5" name="category[]" value="5"/>
```

I can print out the category array fine and it gives me the correct values according to which checkboxes i clicked. I just can't seem to loop through them to insert multiple rows in my database.

After inserting into database the database should look like this:

```
| USERID | MACHINEID | 
----------------------
|      1 |         1 |  
|      1 |         2 |   
|      1 |         3 |
```

If i only click the first 3 checkboxes.

I was thinking something like this:

```
$array_zone = $_POST['category'];
if(isset($_POST['category']))
{
 for($i = 0; $i < count($array_zone); $i++)
{
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `userPlanDetail` (`user_id`, `machine_id`) VALUES ('$user_id', '  $array_zone[$i]')");
 }
}
```

Comment: incorrect logic. $_POST may have data, but the category section may be empty. Your sample code is also vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so don't use this code at all.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but right now i'm just trying to get the checkboxes inputted into the database. Securing it after that is simple

Comment: Just want to also mention you should be escaping the values before directly placing them in the query. Look up SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

try this, looks you you have white space issues

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `userPlanDetail` (`user_id`, `machine_id`) VALUES ('$user_id', '$array_zone[$i]')");
```

also if there are multiple it would be better insering them like this

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `userPlanDetail` (`user_id`, `machine_id`) 
VALUES ('$user_id', '$array_zone[$i]'), ('$user_id', '$array_zone[$i++]')");
```

they will insert much quicker as a single statement

Look here for more info

[Multiple mysql INSERT statements in one query php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307618/multiple-mysql-insert-statements-in-one-query-php)

also even for testing, mysql_* is still very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If your machineid column is an int it's possible that the space in '  $array_zone[$i]'  is causing you trouble.  Are you checking for mysql errors?

Comment: Currently i'm not checking for errors. I just did and it says foreign key constraint fails. Both the user_id and machine_id are foreign keys