# How to update multiple queries as one

Tags: php, mysql

this is mu query

```
$sql_query= "insert into shortdb1.currency_code set currency_code = 'KWD', 
based_on = 'KWD', currency_rate = '1.00', 
last_update = '2013-07-25 11:41:33';
insert into shortdb1.currency set currency_code = 'KWD', 
language_code = 'EN', currency_name = 'Kuwaiti Dinar';";


    $conn_1->query($sql_query)
```

but i getting error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`insert into shortdb1.currency set currency_code = 'KWD', language_code = 'EN','` at line 4

Comment: sorry its my mistake i enter there

Answer (score 1):

Your queries need to be stored as Strings, i.e.:

```
$sql_query = insert into shortdb1.currency_code set currency_code = 'INR', based_on = 'KWD', currency_rate = '200', last_update = '2013-07-25 11:14:26';
```

needs to be

```
$sql_query = "insert into shortdb1.currency_code set currency_code = 'INR', based_on = 'KWD', currency_rate = '200', last_update = '2013-07-25 11:14:26'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a ton of quotes and semicolons at the end of both query and php sentences:

```
$sql_query = "insert into shortdb1.currency_code set currency_code = 'INR', based_on = 'KWD', currency_rate = '200', last_update = '2013-07-25 11:14:26';";

$sql_query .= "insert into shortdb1.currency set currency_code = 'INR', language_code = 'EN', currency_name = 'Indian Rupee', based_on = 'KWD', currency_rate = '200', last_update   = '2013-07-25 11:14:26';";

$conn_1->query($sql_query);
```

Comment: Did you put down the first line ending exactly like: `';";`?

Comment: yes ike this "insert into shortdb1.currency_code set currency_code = 'INR', based_on = 'KWD', currency_rate = '200', last_update = '2013-07-25 11:14:26';";

Comment: Oh, right. Please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1307645/1167953

Answer (score 1):

if you want to send multiple update queries, you can use transaction

```
$firstQuery = "insert into shortdb1.currency_code set currency_code = 'KWD', based_on = 'KWD', currency_rate = '1.00', last_update = '2013-07-25 11:41:33'";
$secondQuery = "insert into shortdb1.currency set currency_code = 'KWD', language_code = 'EN', currency_name = 'Kuwaiti Dinar';";

try {
    // create transaction
    $conn->beginTransaction();

    // multiple query commands
    $conn->query($firstQuery);
    $conn->query($secondQuery);
    // ect...

    // if we are here, then the above query got passed correctly without exception
    // now we can commit the transaction
    $conn->commit();
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    // if above commands fails, the db gets a rollback task
    $conn->rollback();
}
```

That's a good way to use multiple insert/update queries to the database in one sequence.

The power of transactions is that you can create an array of update queries and loop through that array in the above block, instead of multi-lined queries.

Comment: if an exception got thrown, it will be stored in $e variable. You can use it to log the error message. Just use $e->getMessage() to get the error message.

Comment: for example if there is error in the $firstQuery it updates $secondQuery or show both error?

Comment: if the first query fails, then the program continues to the catch-block * and will ignore the commands after the 1st query. If the 2nd query fails, then the code will jump to the catch block **. In the catch block, it will send a rollback command to undo the previously done querytasks. At *, nothing is rollbacked. But at **, the first query will be rollbacked (thus not updated)

Answer (score 1):

I think your queries are badly formed. The `SET` keyword is used for `UPDATE` queries.

For an `INSERT` query it should be in this form:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3)  
                VALUES (value1, value2, value3);
```