# How can we Interlace the Array with php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to build an SQL statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(`People`, `Places`, `Ideas`)
       VALUES ('40', '15',  null),
              (null, '5',   '10'),
              ('10',  null, '11');
```

We have three arrays with following values....

```
$people = array('45','null','10');
$places = array('15','5','null');
$ideas = array('null','11');
```

How can I build the corresponding SQL Query from my array?

Comment: You'd better use PDO or something similar. `mysql_query()` is deprecated.

Comment: Noway. Unless you have NULL values instead of strings 'null' in your array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple mysql INSERT statements in one query php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307618/multiple-mysql-insert-statements-in-one-query-php)

Comment: You can go through the arrays with a loop, and build the query string. But can be tricky.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I'd think the "expected result" is the query string.

Comment: @MightyPork: That's fine, but there are no attempted solutions. (This text is directly copied from the Off-topic close reason. You'll see it when you get to 3000 rep :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Oh god, just looked at your rep. It's intimidating!

Comment: You haven't explained the problem. Your arrays cannot machinatically create the query string specified (your second array has only two values, you appear to want the machine to 'know' that the second array value should go in the third SQL row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) makes this easy:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO mytable(`People`, `Places`, `Ideas`) VALUES ';

$value_arrs = array($people, $places, $ideas);
$value_arrs_size = count($value_arrs);

for ($i = 0; $i < $value_arrs_size; ++$i) {
    $query .= '(' . implode(', ', $value_arrays[$i]) . ')';

    if ($i < $value_arrs_size - 1) {
        $query .= ', ';
    }
}
```

This will only work as long as your values are all numbers or `null`. You'll need to add quotes around any strings you may want in your SQL statements.

Also, if this is user supplied input, you **have to** [sanitize to prevent SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).