# PHP: How to deal with a GROUP of HTML input text fields

Tags: php, loops

I've got a bunch of `<input type='text' name='input0' />` fields.

The user can add them dynamically so we'd get something like:

```
<input type='text' name='input0' />
<input type='text' name='input1' />
<input type='text' name='input2' />
```

...etc. We don't know how many there will be in total. When the form gets submitted, I want to loop through each of these input fields and assign them to a `$_POST` variable. These are NOT the only input fields in the form, there are other elements such as radio buttons, checkboxes and other text fields. My problem is I need to somehow identify these particular dynamically-generated text fields, and loop through them. How can I do this, when all I get on the server side are the names of the input fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
<input type='text' name='input[]' />
```

then you can:

```
foreach($_POST['input'] as $input){
    echo $input;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Marking as answer in ETA 11 mins

Comment: One more (remotely related) question: If I'm recording each value in a MySQL DB, is it best to insert the query into the `foreach` loop so it's recorded with each iteration? Seems like it would take forever if there are 50 input fields. Or is there a more efficient way of recording all values with one query?

Comment: @user1775598 if you're inserting them into a database, you can build a multi-valued `insert` statement, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307618/multiple-mysql-insert-statements-in-one-query-php then just execute it once you've finished your loop. Make sure you don't leave yourself open to mysql injections though!