# Correct way of using INSERT INTO with my array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am currently using the following INSERT INTO :

```
$sql=  "INSERT INTO orders (Orderdatum, Naam, Woonplaats, Straatnaam, Huisnummer, Telefoon, Aantal, Prijs) 
        VALUES (now(), '$_POST[naam]','$_POST[woonplaats]','$_POST[straatnaam]','$_POST[huisnummer]','$_POST[telefoonnummer]', '$total_number', '$total_price')
        ";

mysql_query($sql);
```

And:

```
foreach ($products as $key => $product){
  $number = isset($_POST[$key])?$_POST[$key]:'';
  if ($number > 0){
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO ordered_products (Ordernr, Product, Aantal) VALUES (last_insert_id(), '$product', '$number')";
    mysql_query($sql2);
    }
}
```

To place the customers order info in 1 table, and the products that are ordered in another. With the correct Ordernr.

This is working just as it should. But i was told the second piece of code the `foreach` shouldn't be done like i have it right now.

Since it will give problems in the long run if I add more values and make bigger arrays.

So i'm wondering what is the correct way of using this `foreach`?

---

Dont get me wrong, my code is working as it should, no problems. But i was told this isn't the right way

Comment: This would be a good starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307618/multiple-mysql-insert-statements-in-one-query-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$InsertData = array();
$Last_Insert_Id = mysql_insert_id();

foreach ($products as $key => $product){
   $number = isset($_POST[$key])?$_POST[$key]:'';

   if ($number > 0){
        $InsertData[] = "('{$Last_Insert_Id}', '{$product}', '{$number}')";
   }
}


$sql2 = "INSERT INTO ordered_products (Ordernr, Product, Aantal) 
          VALUES " . implode(", ", $InsertData) . " ";
mysql_query($sql2);
```

Comment: Can you maybe tell me why this is the better approach, because according to my knowledge this doesn't seem THAT different from my original foreach

Comment: @Farewyth Because inserting in loop cause multiple round trips to the database, and significantly slower scripts.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But does it completely outdo my script? Or should i just use this kind of script from now on even if its a little array like my example? maximum 11 products.

Comment: @Farewyth, It could be any amount of data array, and a single insert query is better.