# Insert in two tables at the same time with IF

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning friends!!

I'm trying to insert data into two tables at the same time. The first condition IF is okay, but the second that is ELSE is not fine. I am including my insertion code below. I've tried it with ELSE, with ELSEIF even with the IF's, but it is not working.

```
if (isset($_POST['save')) {
    if (@$_POST['id_confrontations'] == "") {
        @$description = $_POST['description'];
        @$dt_confrontation = $_POST['dt_confrontation'];
        @$id_competitions = $_POST['id_competitions'];
        @$id_stages = $_POST['id_stages'];
        @$score1 = $_POST['score1'];
        @$score2 = $_POST['score2'];
        @$mandant_club = $_POST['mandant_club'];
        @$visitor club = $_POST['visitor_club'];
        @$situation = $_POST['situation'];
        @$phase = $_POST['phase'];
        @$id_trainers = $_POST['id_trainers'];
        @$history = $_POST['history'];

        //saves the record in the "confrontations" table - In this case insertion is perfect

        $confrontations = "INSERT INTO confrontations 
                            (description, dt_confrontation, id_competitions, 
                            stadiums_id, score1, scoring2, binder_club, 
                            situation, stage, id_trainers, history) 
                VALUES ('$description','$dt_confrontation','$id_competitions',
                        '$id_estadios','$score1','$score2',
                        '$mandant_club','$visitor_club','$situation',
                        '$stage','$id_trainers','$historia')';

        //saves the record in the "panel" table - In IF insertion is perfect, but in ELSE it inserts as if it were IF
        //In the IF rule the mandating_club would be == '1', so the GF would receive the score1 and the GC would receive the score2
        //In the ELSE rule the visiting_club would be == '1', so the GC would receive the score1 and the GF would receive the score2

        if(visiting_club != '1'){
            $panel = "INSERT INTO panel (GF, GC, binant_club, visitor_club, id_competitions, status, status) 
                    VALUES ('$score1','$scor2','$mandant_club','$visitor_club',
                            '$id_competitions','$id_states','$situation')";
        }else{
            $panel = "INSERT INTO panel 
                                (GC, GF, mandant_club, visitor_club, 
                                id_competitions, status, status) 
                    VALUES ('$score1','$scor2','$mandant_club',
                            '$visitor_club','$id_competitions',
                            '$id_states','$situation')";
        }
```

Thank you all for your attention and suggestions.

Comment: start with using prepared statements with parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Your quotes are mismatched. You started the `INSERT` with `"`, but you ended it with `'`.

Comment: `visiting_club` should be `$visiting_club` -- you're missing the `$`.

Comment: also you can use multiinsert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307618/multiple-mysql-insert-statements-in-one-query-php

Comment: @nbk That's only for inserting multiple rows into the same table, not different tables.

Comment: Another typo: `$scor2` should be `$score2`.

Comment: Way too much use of the `@` error silencer

Comment: "*is not working*" falls short of conveying any useful information about the observed behavior ... error message? too many rows added? row added but has wrong values?  (StackOverflow is intended for question/answer, it is _not_ a debugging service.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for these observations.

Comment: @nbk The links you provided helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have huge wrong data and missing variable

1. This variable @$visitor club = $_POST['visitor_club']; should @$visitor_club
2. You declare variable @$history = $_POST['history']; But you call $historia variable when insert data into [confrontations] table.
3. You start ["] double quotation for insert data into table [confrontations] but end ['] single quotation.
4. Your insert code for table [confrontations]. You declare [11] column name but you declare [12] column value. So you should now same column name and value into data insert code.
5. When you insert data to [panel] table, your code was below

   INSERT INTO panel (GF, GC, binant_club, visitor_club, id_competitions, status, status)

here last two column (status, status) name is same. You can't insert data using the same column name.

Note: if you want to create a insert code with MySQL. Go to PHP MyAdmin and select your database >> Select your table >> Click Insert >> Insert a dummy data >> Now MySQL generate a auto insertion code for PHP. Use this code for your insert data by change column value.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. It is working now.