# Insert multiple rows into MySQL Table ( PHP problem )

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

how can I insert multiple rows into MySQL with php so that after one single query the MySQL Table would look like:

| user_id | Message | Date | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1243 | Hello world! | 06.04.2021 | First Message |
| 5265 | Hi John! | 07.04.2021 | Second Message |

Comment: Both INSERT .. SELECT and INSERT .. VALUES allows to insert more than one row (rather than INSERT .. SET).

Comment: Or use foreach() loop in your PHP file. But multiple inserts are better. Something like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307618/multiple-mysql-insert-statements-in-one-query-php/1307652

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert multiple rows with one query MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502032/insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query-mysql)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502032/insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query-mysql You can follow this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MYSQL prepared statement

```
    include(your connection code...)

    // prepare and bind
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO yourtable(user_id, message, date, subject) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("isss", $user_id, $message, $date, $subject);

    @foreach statement for your data
    
    // set parameters and execute
    $user_id= $data->id;
    $message= $data->message;
    $date= $data->date;
    $subject= $data->subject;
    $stmt->execute();
    
    @endforeach
```

this method can even secure your app from SQL injection