# SQLite (PHP) optimization: query a number of words at once, but keep the results in the order they were sent

Tags: php, sqlite, optimization

In PHP, I receive a list of anywhere from 1 to 300 user-provided words. For each of them (loop), I run the following query sequentially and do stuff with the results. Some words may not return anything (empty return array). The loop code is:

```
    // The $words array contains on average 300 words
    foreach ($words as $key => $value) {
        $word = $value;
        if ($word != "") {
            $word = str_replace("’", "'", $word);
            $word = str_replace("᾿", "'", $word);
            $wordlc = mb_strtolower($word, "UTF-8");
            $wordlcclean = str_replace("'", "", $wordlc);
            $wordlcclean = str_replace("‘", "", $wordlcclean);

            $SQLITEPDO_PRST = $SQLITEPDO->prepare("SELECT WordPol, IsFirstCap FROM tWords WHERE WordPol = :WordPol OR WordPol = :WordPol2");
            $SQLITEPDO_PRST->bindValue(":WordPol", $wordlc);
            $SQLITEPDO_PRST->bindValue(":WordPol2", $wordlcclean);
            $SQLITEPDO_PRST->execute() or die($SQLITEPDO->errorInfo());
            $resultsArr = $SQLITEPDO_PRST->fetchAll();
            $timesFound = count($resultsArr);
            /* Do stuff here with $resultsArr */
        }
    }
```

I would like to optimize (if possible) the process and query *all* words at once in one query, but I have the results come in the same order as the words used in input, and know which result belongs to each word. Some words may not return any results, but I still want to know that it did not.

I'm hoping that if this is possible, it could possibly speed up the process.
The requirements are: [PDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Development_and_community) and prepared statements as the input is user provided and I want to be safe.

I was thinking using the `IN()` statement, but I don't think I can use PDO/prepared statements with that, and secondly I'm not sure I will receive the results in the same order as the words. This is for a spell checker, so I need to know for each word, if it exists in the dictionary.

Is there a way to do this and if so, how? Is there anything else I can/should do?

Comment: Depending on the values of `$apostrBef` and `$apostrAft` you will not be issuing a `bindValue` for either `":WordPolApostr"` or `":WordPolClean"` in the loop. Are you doing an initial `bindValue` call for these bind variables prior to entering the loop? And where do these variables come from? You need to update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Booboo I simplified and updated the code, because that branching was not really necessary, it was confusing.

Comment: _"I was thinking using the IN() statement but I don't think I can use PDO/prepared statements with that"_ - you can, but you will have to create your statement syntax dynamically, so that you have one placeholder in there for each value inside the IN(...), and you will have to bind the according number of parameters, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/14767530/1427878

Comment: And the replacements/modification you are currently doing with the `$word` variable in PHP, you would have to do in the SQL statement itself then. (SQLite has `REPLACE()` and `LOWER()`.)

Comment: @CBroe would the IN() statement be an actual optimization? as in faster? and the results come in the same order? because the loop is for a spellchecker, I want to know for each word, if the word exists in the dictionary

Comment: Probably, yes, but it can't be guaranteed upfront, you will have to test & see. But in general, use of database queries in loops is discouraged in favor of one statement that gathers all the necessary data, because sending statements to the database and retrieving the results comes with a certain amount of overhead in itself.

Comment: @CBroe would the results come in the same order as the words are in the array ? "good"=>1, "goodo"=>0 etc.

Comment: Not sure if that can be guaranteed. In MySQL it could be forced by using FIND_IN_SET with the same word list again in the ORDER BY clause, but I am not sure if SQLite has something comparable. But you could fetch all the results and order them afterwards in PHP real quick, before you process them any further.

Comment: How many words in a typical list to check, how many in the biggest list and how many in the table twords?

Comment: @Kendle the typical list to check is anywhere from 1 to 500 words, typically around 300. tWords table contains about ~3m words

Comment: @CBroe `FIND_IN_SET` and `FIELD` are not available in `sqlite` and result an error: `Code: HY000. Msg: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: FIND_IN_SET`. However getting rows sorted may be done by using `JOIN` with a `TEMPORARY TABLE` that has the input words and the incremental column used as the argument for the `ORDER BY` or by using PHP for sorting the results as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I provide you an example solution, I would like to share a few words of comment to the code you pasted, so you be able to understand why I wrote the code in different way.

You have the line:

```php
$SQLITEPDO_PRST->execute() or die($SQLITEPDO->errorInfo());
```

But the [PDO:errorInfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) method returns an array, not a string that is accepted by die()—an equivalent of [exit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php). Therefore, in case of any error, you will not see any other information that just the literal text: *Array*.

You may convert an array to string by [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```php
$SQLITEPDO_PRST->execute() or die("sqlite err: " . implode(", ", $SQLITEPDO->errorInfo()));
```

Before that `$SQLITEPDO_PRST->execute()` you have a plenty of commands that may fail as well, but there isn't any testing if their execution was successful.

```php
$SQLITEPDO_PRST = $SQLITEPDO->prepare("SELECT ...");
$SQLITEPDO_PRST->bindValue(":WordPol", $wordlc);
$SQLITEPDO_PRST->bindValue(":WordPol2", $wordlcclean);
```

There should be separate test for each of them, because it is common that preparation or binding of values fails.

As you can see, there is a lot of testing if everything went right/wrong when working with [PDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Development_and_community).

Therefore I would like to encourage you to use Exceptions instead. You may configure PDO by passing options with [PDO::setAttribute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) or by passing an array like below so you don't need to test anything and in case of any error the PDO will throw an exception immediately.

An example PDO configuration:

```php
$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$SQLITEPDO = new \PDO('sqlite:'. $sqliteFilePath, null, null, $options);
```

Here is great [PDO Tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/) if you want to know more and [W3 Tutorial on Exceptions](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_exceptions.asp).

Play with the examples I provided you and make invalid SQL query to see how Exceptions are handled.

It is possible to **optimize your query** so no matter the quantity of user provided words you could query database with all of them at once.

For doing that you may use:

`IN` keyword (it works with prepared statements) or

`JOIN` keyword with a `TEMPORARY TABLE`

**Retrieving results in the same order** as words provided by user can be done in two ways.

When using `IN` keyword you need to use the array of user provided words as the source of the order and sort the retrieved data in PHP. That is because sqlite does not support `ORDER BY FIELD (...)`, that is supported by MySQL.

When using `TEMPORARY TABLE` you may use its column that has incremental integer and sort as any other table by using simple `ORDER BY`.

**Using `IN` and PHP sorting example.**

Using prepared statements with `IN` in case you don't know quantity of words upfront is possible by using binding with `?` instead of `:bindName` labels.

An example of binding by using question mark placeholders ([Example #2 from PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php))

```php
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(2, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Note that first argument of `bindParam()` is an integer and it starts from `1` not from `0`. It is also important to have numbers incrementing by 1 continuously = 1,2,3 an not 1,3,4 (2 skipped) .

In your application if you receives array of unknown number elements then you need to count the number of elements and make exactly the same amount of `?` inside the `IN ()`.

For two words sent by the user, your query is:

```sql
SELECT `WordPol`, `IsFirstCap` FROM tWordsTest WHERE `WordPol` IN (?, ?) ORDER BY (WordPol);
```

And if the user sends 100 words then there should be 100x `?` separated by comma `,` and so on.

You may use `count($userSentWordsParsed)` to get the number of words passed by user and [str_repeat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat) to get exact amount of `?` that equal to the number of words passed by the user:

```php
$userSentWordsParsedCount = count($userSentWordsParsed);
$additionalQuestionMarksCount = $userSentWordsParsedCount - 1;
$in  = str_repeat('?,', $additionalQuestionMarksCount) . '?';
$query = "SELECT `WordPol`, `IsFirstCap` FROM tWordsTest WHERE `WordPol` IN (" . $in . ") ORDER BY (WordPol);";
```

Having that query you need to make prepare and binding to PDO parametres like in the example from PHP manual above.

You can do it in the foreach loop that iterates over the data.

Simple, but handy, is this function that prepares, binds data and executes a statement:

```php
function pdoPrepareAndExecute(
    \PDO $connection,
    string $query,
    array $bindData = []
) : \PDOStatement
{
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);

    if (!empty($bindData)) {
        foreach ($bindData as $entry) {
            $stmt->bindParam(
                $entry['bindName'],
                $entry['bindValue'],
                $entry['bindType']
            );
        }
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt;
}
```

So you can use it this way:

```php
#---------- build query ------------
$userSentWordsParsedCount = count($userSentWordsParsed);
$additionalQuestionMarksCount = $userSentWordsParsedCount - 1;
$in  = str_repeat('?,', $additionalQuestionMarksCount) . '?';
$query = "SELECT `WordPol`, `IsFirstCap` FROM tWordsTest WHERE `WordPol` IN (" . $in . ") ORDER BY (WordPol);";
#---------- build query ------------

# --------- create data with binding arr -------
$data = [];
$placeholderPosition = 1;
foreach ($userSentWordsParsed as $word) {
    $data[] = [
        'bindName' => $placeholderPosition,
        'bindValue' => $word,
        'bindType' => \PDO::PARAM_STR
    ];
    $placeholderPosition++;
}
# --------- create data with binding arr -------

#---------- execute query ----------
$stmt = pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query, $data);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

in many places of your code.

Once you have results, there is a need to use the `$userSentWordsParsed` as a source of the order for sorting the `$results`.

The example generates output:

```
----------------------------------------
userSentWordsParsed:
Array
(
    [0] => cherry
    [1] => lemon
    [2] => potato
    [3] => banana
    [4] => carrot
    [5] => raspberry
)
----------------------------------------
Display results:
cherry (in database)
lemon (in database)
potato
banana (in database)
carrot
raspberry (in database)
```

The example PHP Code:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {

    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    # change directory to any temporary
    $saveDir = '/usr/share/nginx/tmp';

    $separatorCount = 40; // just for printing msg

    // create directory
    if (!file_exists($saveDir)) {
        mkdir($saveDir);
    }

    // -------- connect to db
    $sqliteFilePath = $saveDir . '/sqlite.db';

    $options = [
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $SQLITEPDO = new \PDO('sqlite:'. $sqliteFilePath, null, null, $options);
    // -------- connect to db

    function pdoPrepareAndExecute(
        \PDO $connection,
        string $query,
        array $bindData = []
    ) : \PDOStatement
    {
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);

        if (!empty($bindData)) {
            foreach ($bindData as $entry) {
                $stmt->bindParam(
                    $entry['bindName'],
                    $entry['bindValue'],
                    $entry['bindType']
                );
            }
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }

    #------ Create table ---------
    // an example table of tags in a database

    # CAUTION: It may delete your database table
    # if you change tWordsTest to tWords
    # remove that DROP TABLE if you want use that
    # with your target database

    // drop any previous table with its content
    $query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tWordsTest;";
    pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query);

    // create new table for tags
    $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tWordsTest (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        WordPol TEXT,
        IsFirstCap INTEGER
    );";
    pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query);
    #------ Create table ----------

    // content of the example table
    $wordInTable = [
        'apple',
        'banana',
        'orange',
        'lemon',
        'raspberry',
        'cherry',
        'grapefruit',
        'kiwi',
    ];

    #----------- insert data into table -----------
    $query = "INSERT INTO tWordsTest (WordPol, IsFirstCap) VALUES (:WordPol, :IsFirstCap);";

    $firstCap = 0;
    foreach($wordInTable as $WordPol) {
        $data = [
            [
                'bindName' => ':WordPol',
                'bindValue' => $WordPol,
                'bindType' => \PDO::PARAM_STR
            ],
            [
                'bindName' => ':IsFirstCap',
                'bindValue' => $firstCap,
                'bindType' => \PDO::PARAM_INT
            ],
        ];
        pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query, $data);
    }
    #----------- insert data into table -----------

    #---------- Test insert -------------
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tWordsTest ";

    $stmt = pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo str_repeat('-', $separatorCount) . \PHP_EOL;
    echo "Data in table:" . \PHP_EOL;
    print_r($results);
    #---------- Test insert -------------

    # example tags sent by user
    $userSentWords = [
        'cherry',
        'lemon',
        'potato',
        'banana',
        'carrot',
        'raspberry'
    ];

    #---------- parse words ------------

    function parseWords(array $inputWordsTest) : array
    {
        $userSentWordsParsed = [];
        foreach ($inputWordsTest as $key => $value) {
            $word = $value;
            if ($word != "") {
                $word = str_replace("’", "'", $word);
                $word = str_replace("᾿", "'", $word);
                $wordlc = mb_strtolower($word, "UTF-8");
                $wordlcclean = str_replace("'", "", $wordlc);
                $wordlcclean = str_replace("‘", "", $wordlcclean);

                $userSentWordsParsed[] = $word;
                $userSentWordsParsed[] = $wordlcclean;
            }
        }
        // remove possible duplicates
        $userSentWordsParsed = array_unique($userSentWordsParsed);

        // make keys ascending and incremental by 1 without missing integers (PDO binding Requirement)
        $userSentWordsParsed = array_values($userSentWordsParsed);

        return $userSentWordsParsed;
    }

    $userSentWordsParsed = parseWords($userSentWords);

    echo str_repeat('-', $separatorCount) . \PHP_EOL;
    echo "userSentWordsParsed:" . \PHP_EOL;
    print_r($userSentWordsParsed);

    #---------- build query ------------
    $userSentWordsParsedCount = count($userSentWordsParsed);
    $additionalQuestionMarksCount = $userSentWordsParsedCount - 1;
    $in  = str_repeat('?,', $additionalQuestionMarksCount) . '?';
    $query = "SELECT `WordPol`, `IsFirstCap` FROM tWordsTest WHERE `WordPol` IN (" . $in . ") ORDER BY (WordPol);";
    #---------- build query ------------

    # --------- create data with binding arr -------
    $data = [];
    $placeholderPosition = 1;
    foreach ($userSentWordsParsed as $word) {
        $data[] = [
            'bindName' => $placeholderPosition,
            'bindValue' => $word,
            'bindType' => \PDO::PARAM_STR
        ];
        $placeholderPosition++;
    }
    # --------- create data with binding arr -------

    #---------- execute query ----------
    $stmt = pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query, $data);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo str_repeat('-', $separatorCount) . \PHP_EOL;
    echo "Results unsorted:" . \PHP_EOL;
    print_r($results);
    #---------- execute query ----------

    // name of the key that holds words in returned rows from DB
    $sortKey = 'WordPol';

    # ------------ get not matched words ----
    // get a flat array having only words from results rows.
    $foundWordsInDb = array_column($results, $sortKey);

    // substract from user wordList these words that were found in the db
    $notFoundWords = array_diff($userSentWordsParsed, $foundWordsInDb);

    if (!empty($notFoundWords)) {
        // make keys ascending without missing integers
        $notFoundWords = array_values($notFoundWords);
    }
    # ------------ get not matched words ----

    # ------------ sort results -------------
    $resultsSorted = [];
    // for each word that user sent (in the order it was sent)
    foreach ($userSentWordsParsed as $userWord) {
        // iterate over all rows of database returned results
        foreach($results as $row) {
            $wordInDatabase = $row[$sortKey];
            // if the word in db is same as user's word
            if ($wordInDatabase === $userWord) {
                // put it on sorted results
                $resultsSorted[] = $row;
            }
        }
    }
    # ------------ sort results -------------

    echo str_repeat('-', $separatorCount) . \PHP_EOL;
    echo "resultsSorted:" . \PHP_EOL;
    print_r($resultsSorted);

    echo str_repeat('-', $separatorCount) . \PHP_EOL;
    echo "notFoundWords:\n";
    print_r($notFoundWords);

    # -------- combine results ------------
    $combinedResults = [];

    // get result as [ rowIndex => 'tagName' ]
    $foundWords = array_column($resultsSorted, $sortKey);

    // switch places of key and value to [ 'tagName' => rowIndex ]
    $foundWords = array_flip($foundWords);

    // create combined results from found in the db tags
    // and not found (notFoundWords)
    foreach ($userSentWordsParsed as $word) {
        $row = [];
        // if the tag was not found in the DB
        if (in_array($word, $notFoundWords)) {
            // create row with word name and present = 0
            $row = [$sortKey => $word, 'present' => 0];

        // tag was found in the DB
        } else {
            $key = $foundWords[$word]; // get index of row for that word
            $row = $resultsSorted[$key]; // get row of of found word

            // add key present with value 1 to row
            $row = array_merge($row, ['present' => 1]);
        }
        $combinedResults[] = $row;
    }

    echo str_repeat('-', $separatorCount) . \PHP_EOL;
    echo "Combinded restults:\n";
    print_r($combinedResults);
    # -------- combine results ------------

    # -------- display results ------------
    echo str_repeat('-', $separatorCount) . \PHP_EOL;
    echo "Display results:\n";

    foreach ($combinedResults as $result) {
        if ($result['present'] === 1) {
            echo $result['WordPol'] . ' (in database)' . \PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            echo $result['WordPol'] . \PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    # -------- display results ------------

} catch (Throwable $e) {
    $msg = 'There was an error. ';
    $msg .= 'Code: ' . $e->getCode() . '. ';
    $msg .= 'Msg: ' . $e->getMessage() . '. ';
    $msg .= 'Location: ' . $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $msg;

    // get only file and line locations from the trace
    $callback = function ($entry) {
        return $entry['file'] . ':' . $entry['line'];
    };
    $traceArr = array_map($callback, $trace = $e->getTrace());

    echo "Execution flow:" . PHP_EOL;
    print_r($traceArr);
    exit;
}
```

Example using `TEMPORARY TABLE` and `JOIN`

Using a temporary table has the advantage that you don't need to sort anything in the PHP application, so it is much simpler and less prone to any errors. Also if you create a temporary table then it is possible to create it with an additional column that has incremental integer of order similarly to keys of the array with user's words. That incremental column later can be used for receiving results in the same order that is in the temporary table that was populated with the values of user's words.

```php
$query =
"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_word_list (
    `input_order` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `user_word` TEXT
);";
```

Then if you make `LEFT JOIN`

```php
$query =
"SELECT
    `temp_word_list`.`input_order`,
    `user_word`,
    `WordPol`,
    `IsFirstCap`
FROM `temp_word_list` LEFT JOIN `tWordsTest`
ON `temp_word_list`.`user_word` = `tWordsTest`.`WordPol`
ORDER BY `temp_word_list`.`input_order`
```

You will get all the user's words as results (even if they are not in the database) plus you may have results sorted in the order of the user's words by column `input_order` from the `temp_word_list`.

x - temp_word_list

y - tWordsTest

[image: Left JOIN]

See more [examples of JOINs visualization](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/sql-joins-visualized-d2f01909e07d)

The result output of the code:

```
userSentWordsParsed:
Array
(
    [0] => cherry
    [1] => lemon
    [2] => potato
    [3] => banana
    [4] => carrot
    [5] => raspberry
)
----------------------------------------
Display results:
cherry (in database)
lemon (in database)
potato
banana (in database)
carrot
raspberry (in database)
```

PHP Code:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

try {

    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    # change directory to any temporary
    $saveDir = '/usr/share/nginx/tmp';

    $separatorCount = 40; // just for printing msg

    // create directory
    if (!file_exists($saveDir)) {
        mkdir($saveDir);
    }

    // -------- connect to db
    $sqliteFilePath = $saveDir . '/sqlite.db';

    $options = [
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $SQLITEPDO = new \PDO('sqlite:'. $sqliteFilePath, null, null, $options);
    // -------- connect to db

    function pdoPrepareAndExecute(
        \PDO $connection,
        string $query,
        array &$bindData = []
    ) : \PDOStatement
    {
        $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);

        if (!empty($bindData)) {
            foreach ($bindData as &$entry) {
                $stmt->bindParam(
                    $entry['bindName'],
                    $entry['bindValue'],
                    $entry['bindType']
                );
            }
        }

        $stat = $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    }

    #------ Create table ---------
    // an example table of tags in a database

    # CAUTION: It may delete your database table
    # if you change tWordsTest to tWords
    # remove that DROP TABLE if you want use that
    # with your target database

    // drop any previous table with its content
    $query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tWordsTest;";
    pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query);

    // create new table for tags
    $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tWordsTest (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        WordPol TEXT,
        IsFirstCap INTEGER
    );";
    pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query);
    #------ Create table ----------

    // content of the example table
    $wordInTable = [
        'apple',
        'banana',
        'orange',
        'lemon',
        'raspberry',
        'cherry',
        'grapefruit',
        'kiwi',
    ];

    #----------- insert data into table -----------
    $query = "INSERT INTO tWordsTest (WordPol, IsFirstCap) VALUES (:WordPol, :IsFirstCap);";

    $firstCap = 0;
    foreach($wordInTable as $WordPol) {
        $data = [
            [
                'bindName' => ':WordPol',
                'bindValue' => $WordPol,
                'bindType' => \PDO::PARAM_STR
            ],
            [
                'bindName' => ':IsFirstCap',
                'bindValue' => $firstCap,
                'bindType' => \PDO::PARAM_INT
            ],
        ];
        pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query, $data);
    }
    #----------- insert data into table -----------

    #---------- Test insert -------------
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tWordsTest ";

    $stmt = pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo str_repeat('-', $separatorCount) . \PHP_EOL;
    echo "Data in table:" . \PHP_EOL;
    print_r($results);
    #---------- Test insert -------------

    # example tags sent by user
    $userSentWords = [
        'cherry',
        'lemon',
        'potato',
        'banana',
        'carrot',
        'raspberry'
    ];

    #---------- parse words ------------

    function parseWords(array $inputWordsTest) : array
    {
        $userSentWordsParsed = [];
        foreach ($inputWordsTest as $key => $value) {
            $word = $value;
            if ($word != "") {
                $word = str_replace("’", "'", $word);
                $word = str_replace("᾿", "'", $word);
                $wordlc = mb_strtolower($word, "UTF-8");
                $wordlcclean = str_replace("'", "", $wordlc);
                $wordlcclean = str_replace("‘", "", $wordlcclean);

                $userSentWordsParsed[] = $word;
                $userSentWordsParsed[] = $wordlcclean;
            }
        }
        // remove possible duplicates
        $userSentWordsParsed = array_unique($userSentWordsParsed);

        // make keys ascending and incremental by 1 without missing integers (PDO binding Requirement)
        $userSentWordsParsed = array_values($userSentWordsParsed);

        return $userSentWordsParsed;
    }

    $userSentWordsParsed = parseWords($userSentWords);

    echo str_repeat('-', $separatorCount) . \PHP_EOL;
    echo "userSentWordsParsed:" . \PHP_EOL;
    print_r($userSentWordsParsed);


    ########## DIFFERENT CODE BELOW ############


    #------ Create table ---------
    // an example table of tags in a database
    $query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_word_list;";
    pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query);

    $query =
    "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_word_list (
        `input_order` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        `user_word` TEXT
    );";
    pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query);
    #------ Create table ----------

    #----------- insert data into table -----------
    // Prepare INSERT statement.
    $query = "INSERT INTO temp_word_list (user_word) VALUES (:user_word);";

    foreach($userSentWordsParsed as &$word) {
        $data =
        [
            [
                'bindName' => ':user_word',
                'bindValue' => $word,
                'bindType' => \PDO::PARAM_STR,

            ]
        ];
        pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query, $data);
    }

    #----------- insert data into table -----------

    #---------- build query ------------
    # query for all user words
    $query =
    "SELECT
        `temp_word_list`.`input_order`,
        `user_word`,
        `WordPol`,
        `IsFirstCap`
    FROM `temp_word_list` LEFT JOIN `tWordsTest`
    ON `temp_word_list`.`user_word` = `tWordsTest`.`WordPol`
    ORDER BY `temp_word_list`.`input_order`
    ;";
    #---------- build query ------------

    # query for user words not present in the DB
    // $query =
    // "SELECT
    //     `temp_word_list`.`input_order`,
    //     `user_word`,
    //     `WordPol`,
    //     `IsFirstCap`
    // FROM `temp_word_list` LEFT JOIN `tWordsTest`
    // ON `temp_word_list`.`user_word` = `tWordsTest`.`WordPol`
    // WHERE `WordPol` IS NULL
    // ORDER BY `temp_word_list`.`input_order`
    // ;";

    #----------- prepare query ---------

    #---------- execute query ----------
    $stmt = pdoPrepareAndExecute($SQLITEPDO, $query);
    $combinedResults = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo str_repeat('-', $separatorCount) . \PHP_EOL;
    echo "Results combined:" . \PHP_EOL;
    print_r($combinedResults);
    #---------- execute query ----------

   # -------- display results ------------
   echo str_repeat('-', $separatorCount) . \PHP_EOL;
   echo "Display results:\n";

   foreach ($combinedResults as $result) {
       if (!empty($result['WordPol'])) {
           echo $result['user_word'] . ' (in database)' . \PHP_EOL;
       } else {
           echo $result['user_word'] . \PHP_EOL;
       }
   }
   # -------- display results ------------

} catch (Throwable $e) {
    $msg = 'There was an error. ';
    $msg .= 'Code: ' . $e->getCode() . '. ';
    $msg .= 'Msg: ' . $e->getMessage() . '. ';
    $msg .= 'Location: ' . $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $msg;

    // get only file and line locations from the trace
    $callback = function ($entry) {
        return $entry['file'] . ':' . $entry['line'];
    };
    $traceArr = array_map($callback, $trace = $e->getTrace());

    echo "Execution flow:" . PHP_EOL;
    print_r($traceArr);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: This was insightful on so many levels. And I forgot to thank you, shame on me. Thank you. I haven't yet implemented it, but when I do, I will try both ways, to see if there is a meaningful difference in performance. I have this feeling that creating the temporary table may be slower, will see.

Comment: @MirrorMirror No worries. I'm happy you found my answer insightful. I did not expect an immediate answer because I was aware that I put a lot of information to digest. For the temporary table example you may use [multiple VALUES as with single INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19569248/1174405) to have optimal performance. If the data for the INSERT is stored inside another table then you may Combine [SELECT with INSERT](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_insert_into_select.asp) so the data does not leave the database but is just copied from one table to the other (tmp table in your case)