# How to create sql insert query dynamically in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an application where I am generating pins dynamically based on user's input and storing them into mySql database.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblpin ('pinId', 'ownerId', 'usedby', 'status') 
    VALUES
        for($i=0;$i<$npin;$i++)
        {
            ('$pin[$i]','$ownerid', 'Free', '1');
        }
    ;";
```

**how can I do that?**

Comment: By not mixing the **code** and the **data**

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Great. So, could you provide an example?

Comment: can you write the plain query manually, without php? so - do that, then split sql string into constant and repetitive parts. after this: replace repetitive parts with loop and construct them with php.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblpin ('pinId', 'ownerId', 'usedby', 'status') VALUES ";
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($pin); $i++) {
    if ($i>0)
        $sql .= ", ";
    $sql .= "('$pin[$i]', '$ownerid', 'Free', '1')";
}
```

Of course you need to escape the values of $pin in case they contain any characters which [could mess with the SQL query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: strings in php are concatenated with "." and ";" in the end of query for mysql_query() is a wrong char due to it accepts one and only one query. and the latest: `foreach` is more handy in this case.

Comment: @cherouvim :ya I got that , final `$sql` is coming fine but whet I call `mysql_query($sql);` , it is not inserting data into db.why?

Comment: @nectar: is there an error? if you do echo $sql, does the statement look good?

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO xy (a,b,c,d) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
foreach ($pins as $i) {
   $s->execute($i,$ownerID,"free",1);
}
```

Comment: i bet OP used bulk insert for some performance reasons, but this would work too.

Answer (score -1):

Something like

```
$sql = sprintf( "INSERT INTO `tblpin` (`pinId`, `ownerId`, `usedby`, `status`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
    generatePIN($pin),
    mysql_real_escape_string($ownerId),
    mysql_real_escape_string($usedBy),
    mysql_real_escape_string( $status) );
```

or (edited for Conspicuous Compiler)

```
$pins = generatePINS($user); // ? however they're generated
foreach( $pins as $pin) {
    $sql = sprintf( "INSERT INTO `tblpin` (`pinId`, `ownerId`, `usedby`, `status`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
        $pin,
        mysql_real_escape_string($ownerId),
        mysql_real_escape_string($usedBy),
        mysql_real_escape_string( $status) );
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

where generatePIN is your function to make your pin based on whatever the heck you're basing it off of.  or generatePINS returns an array of them

Comment: So, two things: (1) He's trying to do multiple rows of inserts at once with a single SQL statement.  Your solution doesn't do that, I don't think.  (2) Any answer should note that the asker's given code is ripe for SQL injection attacks.  (Your proposed solution has this same flaw.)

Comment: The OP makes no notes of multiple rows - the question is vague. Pins could be a typo, one column, who knows what. the OP makes no mention if he/she is sanitizing his data or not; if the OP does any search re: sql on this site, he/she is sure to find plenty of examples (hell, even some of my answers with tips for him/her)