# insert php array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array $product_array, and when I use print_r($product_array);. The array shows like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => P00100
            [NAME] => Edina
            [PRICE] => $20.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => P00101
            [NAME] => Richfield
            [PRICE] => $21.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => P00102
            [NAME] => Bloomington
            [PRICE] => $22.00
        )
)
```

I set my database table in 4 columes, first one is mainid, and which is auto increment, following with ID, NAME, PRICE, as the keys showed above. 
I would like to insert this array $product_array into mysql.
Can anyone help? Would be very much appreciated!
tks.

Answer (score 18):

```
   $sql = array(); 
    foreach( $myarray as $row ) {
        $sql[] = '('.$row['ID'].', "'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['NAME']).'",
 "'.$row['PRICE'].'")';
    }
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (ID, NAME,PRICE) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

see more details :

[insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql)

Comment: correct the first `$row['PRICE']` to `$row['ID']` and get an up-vote as reward ;)

Comment: @HaimEvgi Haim, I think you should change `mysql_real_query` function which isn't available in php anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code (quick 'n' dirty):

```
foreach($product_array as $v) {
  $query = 'insert into tablename values (null, \'' . $v['id'] . '\', \'' . $v['name'] . '\', ' . $v['price'] . ');'
  mysql_query($query);
}
```