# unable to insert into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123");
mysql_select_db("website_categorization") or die("\n error selecting database" );
$keyword_array = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $tag);                              
foreach($keyword_array as $tag1)                                                      
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO category_keyword(ID_Category, Keyword) VALUES(2,$tag1)");
}

echo "\nAffected rows are ".mysql_affected_rows()."\n";
mysql_close($db);
```

Can u tell me what is the problem with this code??...I intend to insert rows into the category_keyword table from an array $keyword_array. I get errors "Affected rows are -1" and insertion does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote and escape string values.
You should also handle errors, to be notified of them.
You should also write **distinct** statements, to be able to read your code later (as well as let others to read it).

```
$tag1 = mysql_real_escape_string($tag1);
$sql  = "INSERT INTO category_keyword(ID_Category, Keyword) VALUES(2,'$tag1')";
mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
```

Comment: @user641086 you're welcome. Hope you learned some good practice from my answer, to use it with every query you run in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

[insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You should quote **and escape** your string columns

> $tag1 =
>   mysql_real_escape_string($tag1);
>   mysql_query("INSERT INTO
>   category_keyword(ID_Category, Keyword)
>   VALUES(2,'$tag1')");

You should also handle the mysql query errors to know why the query get failed. With the current code you never know why it is failing.It is better to handle mysql errors.

```
mysql_query('Your query') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulte the string $tag in a query, otherwise mysql will think its a column name

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO category_keyword(ID_Category, Keyword) VALUES(2,'".mysql_real_escape_string($tag1)."')");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO category_keyword SET ID_Category=2, Keyword=".$tag1.");
```

Better syntax to understand :)

Comment: that's the syntax for UPDATE query. Even if it would work I would never use it this way!

Comment: @krike in fact, it's quite handy to have similar syntax for both types, lets you reuse your code