# Inserting multiple rows into MySql with one INSERT statement using PHP implode function

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into MySql with only one `INSERT INTO` statement using the `implode` function. It was found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql).

My sample code goes below.

```
$sql[]=array();
$len=count($colour_id);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
{
     $sql[]='('.$colour_id[$i].', '.$_POST['prod_id'].')';
}

$l=count($sql);
foreach($sql as $temp)
{
     echo $temp;
}

echo 'insert into product_colour (colour_id, prod_id)values '.implode(',', $sql);
```

---

The above code simply initializes the `$sql` array and the `foreach` loop iterates over the array and displays the content of the array as follows.

```
Array(1, 1)(2, 1)(3, 1)
```

but while echoing the last statement (insert statement), it shows the following error.

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\wagafashion\ProductColour.php on line 70
insert into product_colour (colour_id, prod_id)values Array,(1, 1),(2, 1),(3, 1)
```

(line no 70 means the last line in the above code snippet).
What changes should be made so that I can insert the values stored in the array into MySql database?

Comment: how about using instead of an array just a string named $sql and do $sql .= '('.$colour_id[$i].', '.$_POST['prod_id'].'), '; Then u will not get the "Array,(1, 1),(2, 1),(3, 1)" thing and only "(1, 1),(2, 1),(3, 1) " btw: u have to delete your last comma, if u use this way.

Comment: Silly mistake was made because I'm not much familiar with PHP. I'm from Java background.

Comment: Yes conversation from one to another language is always a bit tricky. But in PHP you have to read the Errors-Codes really carefully, because they give you good hints, whats wrong with your code. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your code should be:

```
$sql=array();
$len=count($colour_id);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
{
     $sql[]='('.$colour_id[$i].', '.$_POST['prod_id'].')';
}

$l=count($sql);
foreach($sql as $temp)
{
     echo $temp;
}

echo 'insert into product_colour (colour_id, prod_id)values '.implode(',', $sql);
```

Take a look at the first line.

Comment: what is the use of `$temp` here?

Comment: inst the ` $sql[]='('.$colour_id[$i].', '.$_POST['prod_id'].')';` supposed to `be $sql[$i]` ?

Comment: `$sql[]` appends a new field to the end of the array. `$sql[$i]` adds the field `$i` to the array, or if the field already exists, it overrides the data in `$sql[$i]`, so in this example it doesn't matter, but in an other context you may have to choose very carefully, what alternative you should use.

Answer (score 1):

I see an extra comma in your statement (between Array and the first `(`).

Try changing the first line you have there to:

```
$sql = array();
```

What you had there sets the first element of `$sql` to a new array, it doesn't set `$sql` to a new array.

With this, your query should become: `insert into product_colour (colour_id, prod_id)values (1, 1),(2, 1),(3, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the 1st line of this snippet : you're doing `$sql[] = array();` you should write `$sql=array();` if you want a good initializatino.

Don't forget to sanitize your input before sending it to Mysql.