# Add multiply rows on a table. PHP-MySQL

Tags: php

I retrieve part of the below mentioned code from the following url: [insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql)
However I face a problem. My code is as following:

```
//create an array
$array = array();

//add some values

//1st var_dump($array);
var_dump($array);

$msql = array(); 
foreach( $array as $row ) {
    $msql[] = '('.$row['trend'].', '.$row['image_url'].','.$row['sku'].')';
}

 var_dump($msql);   



 $insertData = "INSERT INTO Data_Info (trend, image_url,sku) VALUES ".implode(',', $msql);
 mysql_query($insertData) or die(mysql_error());

 mysql_close($conn);
```

The table that I have created contains three fields-> trend, image_url,sku.

Results of the 1st var_dump:

```
array(6) { 
   [0]=> string(7) "mytrend" 
   [1]=> string(70) "http://re.n.o.coat.png" 
   [2]=> string(12) "militarycoat" 
   [3]=> string(7) "mytrend" 
   [4]=> string(73) "http://re.n.o.padded.png" 
   [5]=> string(15) "signaturepadded" 
}
```

Results of the 2n var_dump:

```
array(6) {
   [0]=> string(8) "(m, m,m)" 
   [1]=> string(8) "(h, h,h)" 
   [2]=> string(8) "(m, m,m)" 
   [3]=> string(8) "(m, m,m)" 
   [4]=> string(8) "(h, h,h)" 
   [5]=> string(8) "(s, s,s)" 
} 
Unknown column 'm' in 'field list'
```

I can't understand what is going wrong. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over every element of your input array and then trying to access properties on a string which has none. (surprised it even does anything)

try a `for` loop.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i+=3)
{
    $msql[] = '('.$array[$i].', '.$array[$i+1].','.$array[$i+2].')';
}
```

or define your $array differently to suit your loop.

Comment: You are correct. However, now I'm taking the follwoing exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '://re.n.o.coat.png,militarycoat)' at line 1

Comment: Can you please add the whole query that was generated? Mysql-syntax errors are always kind of obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an associative array of arrays(multidimensional) with $row['trend'] etc... while you don't have it, as indicated in your first var_dump. your first var_dump should look like this:

```
$array = array(0 => array("trend"=> "value", "image_url" => "value, "sku" => "value"), 1=> array( .... ) and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Unknown column 'm' in 'field list'` is generated by:

```
$insertData = "INSERT INTO Data_Info (trend, image_url,sku) VALUES ".implode(',', $msql);
```

The `VALUES` must be encapsulated in brackets. Also data should be in quotes. It now is:

```
VALUES (m, m, m),(h, h, h)
```

and it should be:

```
VALUES (('m', 'm', 'm'),('h', 'h', 'h'))
       ^                               ^
       |_________encapsulated__________|
```

Otherwise the data is seen as column (`Unknown column 'm' in 'field list'`)

---

Secondly, your array doesn't contain the keys `trend`, `image_url` and `sku`, so the values you get from them are the first letter of each string in that array:

- `(m, m,m)` is from the first letter of `"mytrend"`
- `(h, h,h)` is from `"http://re.n.o.coat.png"`
- etc

So create your array like this:

```
$array = array(0 => array("trend"     => "put", 
                          "image_url" => "something", 
                          "sku"       => "in here"), 
               1 => array("trend"     => "value1", 
                          "image_url" => "value2", 
                          "sku"       => "value3"),
               /* etc.. */
               );
```