# Entering an array into my database using mySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, insert

I know I am doing this completely wrong, but current I have:

```
$genre0 = addslashes(strip_tags($movieInfo[genres][0][name]));
$genreid0 = addslashes(strip_tags($movieInfo[genres][0][id]));
...
$genre4 = addslashes(strip_tags($movieInfo[genres][4][name]));
$genreid4 = addslashes(strip_tags($movieInfo[genres][4][id]));
```

Then

```
mysql_query($query = "INSERT INTO tblMovies (movie_id, genre_id, genre_name) VALUES ($movie_id , $genreid0, $genre0");
...
mysql_query($query = "INSERT INTO tblMovies (movie_id, genre_id, genre_name) VALUES ($movie_id , $genreid4, $genre4");
```

I know this is extremely repetitive, but it is the only way I can figure out that works. I have tried a ton of for each statements to no avail. I have tried following this one [insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql) and a few others, but cannot seem to figure it out.

This is embedded in a SELECT/WHILE statement that runs through a list of movies...

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Switch to PDO. Prepare a statement `INSERT INTO tblMovies (...) VALUES (:movie_id, :genre_id, :genre_name)`. Execute this statement in a loop, once for each genre you have.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **prepared statements** for handy execution of your query:

```
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tblMovies (movie_id, genre_id, genre_name)
                             VALUES (:movie_id , :genreid, :genre")");

      $stmt->bindParam(':movie_id ', $movie_id);
      $stmt->bindParam(':genreid', $genreid);
      $stmt->bindParam(':genre', $genre);

      for($i=0; $i < count($movieInfo['genres']); $i++){
         $movie_id = i;
         $genreid = addslashes(strip_tags($movieInfo['genres'][i]['id']));
         $genre = addslashes(strip_tags($movieInfo['genres'][i]['name']));
         $stmt->execute();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using mysql_XXX:

```
foreach ($movieInfo['genres'] as $genre) {
    $genre = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($genre['name']));
    $genreid = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($genre['id']));
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblMovies (movie_id, genre_id, genre_name) VALUES ($movie_id , '$genreid', '$genre'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would insist that insert multiple records in database by firing single query instead of firing seperate query for each record.

E.g.:

```
INSERT INTO tblMovies
  (genre_id, genre_name)
VALUES
  ('Name 1', 'Value 1'),
  ('Name 2', 'Value 2'),
  ('Name 3', 'Value 3'),
  ('Name 4', 'Value 4');


//Prepare the entire query using foreach and then fire single query.
foreach ($movieInfo['genres'] as $genre) {
    $genre = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($genre['name']));
    $genreid = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($genre['id']));
    $parts[] = "('.$genreid.', '.$genre.')";
}

$str = implode("," $parts);
$query = "INSERT INTO tblMovies (genre_id, genre_name) VALUES ".$str.";";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

**Note:** I have used `mysql` as you have mentioned in question but **it is recommended** to switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`. Also, from the question you have mentioned, I assume that `$movie_id` is auto-increment.