# multiple insert sql query php

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

I have a table with columns ID,departmentID,val

```
create table departmentVal (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), departmentID INT NOT NULL, val BIGINT)

create table departmentID (ID,departmentName)
```

how to do a Multiple insert of val, $count = 10k and  $val = 1234900000001 to 1234900010000  into departmentVal

```
$i = 0;
$count = 10000;
 $va = 1234900000001;
$dptID = 1;

while  ($i < $count){
insert into departmentVal($dptID , $val);
$val++;
}
```

I'm seeking for better solution to do this .

Comment: did you look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql  ?

Comment: You're not using `$count` anywhere

Comment: @ fizzy No, I didnt btw thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(p1 INT)
BEGIN
    SET @x = 0;
    REPEAT 
        INSERT INTO your_table SELECT NULL, field1, field2;
        SET @x = @x + 1; 
    UNTIL @x > p1 END REPEAT;
END