# Inserting a lot of data into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cron

So my situation is the following. I obtain data from a certain source through PHP every 24 hours. Now during that time this data gets changed, new data is added or some is updated. Now when I run a query to insert or update this data each 24 hours it takes a long time for the query to execute. This would not be a problem if the execution time was moderate as I am planning on making this a cron job, however the execution time now is way too high. 
So I was thinking about writing this data from PHP to a CSV file, when I obtain it. And then using this CSV file together with the `MySQL LOAD DATA` function which supposedly inserts a lot of data from a file in a very quick manner.

So the question is it possible to write to a CSV file from PHP and have it formatted in a way that suits the `LOAD DATA INFILE` function, and how can I each 24 hours delete that CSV and create a new one with newly inserted data, and how would I go about properly using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` function with this particular CSV file? Oh and can I make a cron job out of all of this ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using batch inserts? Multiple inserts in one query is faster then one insert in each query. See [http://stackoverflow.com/a/780046/1057527](http://stackoverflow.com/a/780046/1057527)

Comment: This is the correct procedure, actually you described the right way to complete this task. So short answer is: Yes.

Comment: Batch inserts won't help me here.

Comment: Do I need to make a cron job which makes a csv file out of this new data every 24 hours and then make a mysql procedure which uses LOAD DATA to insert this csv into the table, or can I somehow combine these two into one cron job.

Comment: Why do batch inserts don't help you? How many rows do you have to insert? I have tried batch inserts and its at least 6 times faster (at least in my case) with over 100k records. They are under a few seconds. Also, I'm using innoDB with foreign keys, which is slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume you receive data from your source and prepare this array:

```
$x=array(1=>array('1','2','3','4'), 2=>array('5','6','7','8'));
```

create a csv file like this:

```
    $file=fopen(<DIRECTORY_PATH>."file.csv","w");
    if(!$file){
       //error
    }

    $csv_data="";

    foreach($x as $row){
     foreach($row as $element){
        $csv_data.=$element.", ";
     }
    //remove the last comma
    $csv_data.="\n";

    }

    fwrite($file,$csv_data);

$query="load data infile '".<DIRECTORY_PATH>."file.csv"."' into table your_table";
if(!mysqli->query($query))
 printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement its very flexible , you can specify the fields,rows delimiter and many other features. This will allow you to make your csv in any format do you want.`LOAD DATA` is indeed the fastest way to insert data in mysql.

In php you can very simply write data to a file like its shown [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php).

After this indeed you need a cron job that will load the file in mysql, [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/) should be helpful.