# Insert multiple rows using single query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert multipl rows in single query.

```
$firstname = array('Arfan','Awais','Ahmad'.....);
$lastname = array('Haider','k','Raza'..........);
```

**Insert Data:**

```
INSERT INTO `table_nmae`(firstname,lastname)
VALUES
('Arfan','Haider'),('Awais','k'),('Ahmad','Raza');
```

I can do it very easily if these are only three record.
If I did not know how many records are present then I can not able to use the above.
Then what I did do?

**UPDATE:**
If I can not know the numbers of record in array.I can simply use `foreach loop` to do this
But this decrease the performance.

```
foreach($firstname as $f){
foreach($lastname as $l){
   INSERT INTO `table_name`(firstname,lastname)
   VALUES('$f','$l');
}

}
```

Now this time I am using multi query.I think single query is good to performance.

**FOR ONE COLUMN:**
If I had only one column it is very easy to use single query for this.

```
INSERT INTO `table_name`(firstname) VALUES
.implode(',', $firstname);
```

But here is multi column how can I do that for those.
Thanks.....

Comment: Why can't you dynamically construct the insert query to include as many rows to insert as you need?

Comment: Which part of your question is asking about performance?

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` loop if `$firstname` and `$lastname` array are of same length

```
$str = "INSERT INTO `table_nmae`(firstname,lastname) VALUES"; // create string of query
for($i = 0 ;$i< count($firstname); $i++) {
    $str .= "('" . $firstname[$i] . "','" . $lastname[$i] . "'),"; //append the values
}
$str = trim($str, ","); // remove last ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$size_of_array = count( $firstname );

$query = "INSERT INTO `table_nmae`(firstname,lastname) VALUES ";
for($i = 0; $i < $size_of_array; $i++ )
{
    if( $i !== ($size_of_array-1))
      $query .= "('{$firstname[$i]}', '{$lastname[$i]}'),";
    else
     $query .= "('{$firstname[$i]}', '{$lastname[$i]}')";
}
echo $query;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have array of values e.g. $values_arr.

```
$count = count( $values_arr );

$query = "INSERT INTO `table_nmae`(firstname,lastname) VALUES ";
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ )
{
    if( $i == 0)
      $query .= "('{$values_arr[$i]['firstname']}', '{$values_arr[$i]['lastname']}')";
    else
     $query .= ",('{$values_arr[$i]['firstname']}', '{$values_arr[$i]['lastname']}')";
}
echo $query;
```

Comment: This is multi querys You always used `$query` to perfom this task.

Comment: No, here is only 1 insert query, but inserting multiple records with it. So it will be more optimized.