# Inserting an array into MySQL database directly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text file to read which has around 10000 points separated by, 
x1,y1
x2,y2
x3,y3
.
.
10000 times

I read them using a loop in PHP and then store in an array and then I run a loop and insert one line at a time in my database. It takes really long time. Is there any way I can insert the whole array

```
for ($i=0; $i<10000; $i++)

{
    $sql = '
        INSERT INTO `firefly`.`FreeFormPoly` 
            (`markedObjectID`, `order`, `x`, `y`) 
        VALUES 
            ('.$markedObjectsID.', '.$order.', '.$valuesx[i].','.$valuesy[i].')';

    $db->query($sql, $markedObjectsID, $order, $values[1], $values[0]);
}
```

Comment: Duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql

Answer (score 2):

Try using multiple insert statement. Generate one insert and submit the entire statement

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

SO:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `firefly`.`FreeFormPoly` (`markedObjectID`, `order`, `x`, `y`) VALUES';
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++) {
    if($i != 0) $sql .= ',';
    $sql .= '('.$markedObjectsID.', '.$order.', '.$valuesx[i].','.$valuesy[i].')';                         
}
$db->query($sql);
```

Comment: There is a limit to how big of an INSERT you can sent.  You might need an extra loop around this one.  Depending on the size of the SQL, I recall having to limit it to 3,000 grouped inserts, but everybody's will vary.

Comment: Perhaps there is a limit. In that case "batch" them up into as many as you can. No doubt the slowdown is from the SQL parsing so many statements.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `firefly`.`FreeFormPoly` (`markedObjectID`, `order`, `x`, `y`) VALUES';
for($i=0;$i<length;$i++) {
    $sql .= '('.$markedObjectsID.', '.$order.',  .$valuesx[i].','.$valuesy[i].'),';
}
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
$db->query($sql);
```

**Explanation:**

The syntax to enter multiple records is

> INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES(VAL1, VAL2, ....), (...), (...);

In the SQL you are concatenating `(val1,val2,val3),` every time you execute the loop hece you will get an extra `,` in the last position and `substr()` trims it off.

More preferably I would do

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `firefly`.`FreeFormPoly` (`markedObjectID`, `order`, `x`, `y`) VALUES ';
for($i=0;$i<length;$i++) {
    $sql .= '('.$markedObjectsID.', '.$order.',  .$valuesx[i].','.$valuesy[i].'),';
}
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql)
    or die('Error in querying the database');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to speed it up considerably by sending `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before the loop and `COMMIT` after the loop.  One time I had to insert 14,000 data points on SQLite, and it took 20 minutes, but when I put the data in as a transaction it completed in 0.3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can use prepared statements to reduce the network overhead. Assuming PDO:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable (foo, bar, baz) VALUES (:foo, :bar, :baz)');

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':foo' => $data[$i]['foo'],
        ':bar' => $data[$i]['bar'],
        ':baz' => $data[$i]['baz'],
    ));
}
```

Second, you could wrap the whole code inside `$db->beginTransaction()` and `$db->commit()`.