# Insert multiple rows from array saved in a session into table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session-variables

I'm passing multiple state values that are stored in a session variable, into a MySQL table via php using one insert command and I'm wondering if its possible to insert each state value into a different row. I also have an ID saved in a variable that I would like to insert with each state.

```
$campaign_id
```

Each state is stored in this session variable.

```
print_r($_SESSION['stateslist']);
```

Assuming I have two states saved in the `$_SESSION['stateslist']` (NY, CA) and campaign ID 5, I would like my database to look like this

```
campaign_id    state
   5             NY
   5             CA
```

I know it is something similar to this [insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql) but I am having problems inserting each state saved in the session as well as the campaign_id.

Comment: You said  you're already using `INSERT`, I'm guessing it's not working for you? Show us your code.

Comment: hey, no i havent inserted the data yet. I want to know how to do it.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: hey, sorry i meant to say i know how to use the insert command I just need help with the below:                                                                    I'm passing multiple state values that are stored in a session variable, into a MySQL table via php using one insert command and I'm wondering if its possible to insert each state value into a different row. I also have an ID saved in a variable that I would like to insert with each state.

Comment: Can you add your insert query that is not working or have you not formed one yet?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my adopted version of what you want from that answer

```
$tags = explode(',', $_SESSION['stateslist']);

$sql = array(); 
$counter=0;
foreach( $tags as $row ) {
    $counter++;
    $sql[] = '("'.$row.'", '.$campaign[counter].')';
```

Assuming here that you have a campaign array that contains all the corresponding campaign ids

```
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (state, campaign_id) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

Comment: Thanks, I want the campaign ID to be the same for each row. Here is what I Got. The only problem now is that the states are not being added in. My database just has the campaign ID and it says array in the states field. Any idea what I am doing wrong                 $campaign[counter]  = 5;


if(isset($_POST['submit_complete'])){


$tags = explode(',', $_SESSION['stateslist']);

$sql = array();
$counter=0;
foreach( $tags as $row ) {
 $counter++;
  $sql[] = '("'.$row.'", '.$campaign[counter].')';
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO campaign_states (state_abbr, campaign_id) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));

Comment: $campaign[counter]  = 5;



if(isset($_POST['submit_complete'])){



    $tags = explode(',', $_SESSION['stateslist']);

    $sql = array(); 
$counter=0;
foreach( $tags as $row ) {
    $counter++;
    $sql[] = '("'.$row.'", '.$campaign[counter].')';
    }
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO campaign_states (state_abbr,           campaign_id) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));