# Create new table input using join from tables on different server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables on server B called Employee_data and Employee_Salary. I need to create a new table on server A which has columns from both the tables.

```
Employee_Data has Employee_id, join_date, Employee_name, employee_photo_url
Employee_salary has employee_id, employee_ssn, employee_autoincrement_id, emp_salary
```

I need to join them to get Employee_id, name, emp_salary and emp_autoincrement_id where Employee_id are equal.

The join is pretty straightforward but how can I insert the data in a table on a different server A?

I will be using php to auto-update the table on server A daily. Can I pass the result of a query on server B to a table on server A as the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn the concept called as [FEDERATED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) . It is a storage engine that accesses data in tables of remote databases in mysql.

Comment: Is there no way to do this using PHP? Can't I store the selected columns in a resource and then use them to populate the other table, somehow?

Comment: Without connecting two different servers, its straight forward, you just have to have two connection strings. Pull data using one connection string and insert it using another.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The data is pulled as a resource when I execute my first query. How can I use this resource to populate the second table?
The syntax doesn't seem to be available on the internet.

Comment: Its will be normal insert using php, if you don't have huge number of rows just insert using loop. For bulk insert you can check this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql.

Comment: Check this also for bulk data insert http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/106167/what-is-the-best-way-to-insert-a-large-dataset-into-a-mysql-database-or-any-dat