# CodeIgniter insert_batch()

Tags: php, codeigniter

OK i am trying to figure how to use insert_batch

I am tring something like this

```
function checkboxes($data,$category)
    {

        $insert=array(
                        'story'=>$data
                        'category'=>$category
                     );

        $this->db->insert_batch('stories_to_categories',$insert);
    }
```

For $data i have array, which could have range of values and keys

```
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 14
    [3] => 15
    [4] => 18
)
```

For category i will have only one value for example 2

I try to achive in my tabele

```
  story category
------------------------
    1        2
    6        2
    14       2
    15       2
    18       2
```

Could someone help me i am in such a pain!

Comment: [`insert` is for inserting one record and `insert_batch` is for inserting multiple records](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert).  So what is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by making a little modification to your code.
CI documentation shows that batch insert expects an array that is embedded with associative arrays: 1 associative array for each new row to be inserted, mapping the column to the value.

Practically, you would want to build an array like this for your `$insert`:

```
$insert=array(
    array('story'=>1, 'category'=>2).
    array('story'=>6, 'category'=>2).
    array('story'=>14, 'category'=>2).
    array('story'=>15, 'category'=>2).
    array('story'=>18, 'category'=>2).
);
```

Since your category is constant, you might want to use a function:

```
function _insert_($data, $category='2', $options=array('data'=>'story', 'category'=>'category'))
{
    $return = array();
    foreach ($data as $value)
    {
        $return[] = array($options['data']=>$value, $options['category']=>$category);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

You can then have something like the following:

```
$this->db->insert_batch('stories_to_categories',_insert_($data));
```

Hope this helps.

Find Reference(s) below:

See CodeIgniter reference here: [CodeIgniter Active Record: #Insert](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)

**edit**: Codeigniter 3.0 Query Builder Class: [inserting data](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data)

Comment: nice one see my solution

Comment: function checkboxes($category_checkboxes,$last_story_id)
    {
      foreach ($category_checkboxes as $box) 
      {
            $insert[] = array(
                     "category" => $box,
                    "story" => $last_story_id
                 );

        }
      
        $this->db->insert_batch('stories_to_categories',$insert);
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkboxes($category_checkboxes,$last_story_id)
    {
        foreach ($category_checkboxes as $box) 
        {
            $insert[] = array(
                              "category" => $box,
                              "story" => $last_story_id
                             );

        }

        $this->db->insert_batch('stories_to_categories',$insert);
    }
```