# How to create and store the form value in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I have create the form with selection option. Based on the selection i show and hide the form value and i don't know to save it in database. In my code there is selection option i show the form field again.for example if i select the option is 3 i am showing form field 3 times.

I want to store the data in backend(database). How to store the database.

My code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hidden-div').hide();
  $("#select_btn").change(function() {
    toggleFields();
  });

});

function toggleFields() {
  var selectVal = $("#select_btn").val();
  if (selectVal <= 5) {
    $hiddenHtml = $('#hidden-div').clone().html();
    $("#refer").html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectVal; i++) {
      $("#refer").append($hiddenHtml);
    }
  }
}
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Demo </title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="referer" method="post" action="">
  <p>Name:
    <input type="text" name="referer_name" />
  </p>
  <p>Mobile:
    <input type="text" name="referer_mobile" />
  </p>
  <p>Email:
    <input type="text" name="referer_email" />
  </p>
  <p>No of Referrer:
    <select id="select_btn" >
      <option value="0">--Select--</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <div id="hidden-div">
 <div id="text">Referral Details</div>
      <p>Name:
        <input type="text" name="name[]" />
      </p>
      <p>Mobile:
        <input type="text" name="mobile[]" />
      </p>
      <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="email[]" />
      </p>
      
    </div>
    <div id="refer">

    </div>
    <p align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: any form component has to have a name before the value will be passed - try assigning a name to your select, then use that name in the same method as the other form components

Comment: What database? MySQL, MSSQL, django, access? It looks to me like you don't even know that you need to set up your own database. Much, much more learning is needed before anyone can help you with this. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/

Comment: @ChrisJ He has no `action` in his form. he doesn't even have a database (my guess)

Comment: True, but the form doesn't have to have an action, it can technically be assigned in the JS later (although not there at the mo).  It's been tagged mysql, so assumed that would be the context, although there is a suspicion of what you're saying.

Comment: mysql only. I have create the database and table....t i dont how to store the form value

Comment: you need to `connection` code also `insert` statements. based on elements names you can access the values. also We Recommend to use `PDO`

Comment: @KarthiVenture i have the database and table as referrer_details. But i dont know how to pass and store the value based on selection. For example if option is 3 then 3 records insert into database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Demo </title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id ="refer-form" name="refer-form" action="validate.php"  method="post" >
 
  <p>No of Referrer:
    <select id="select_btn" >
      <option value="0">--Select--</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <div id="hidden-div">
 <div id="text">Referrer</div>
      <p>Name:
        <input type="text" name="name[]" />
      </p>
      <p>Mobile:
        <input type="text" name="mobile[]" />
      </p>
      <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="email[]" />
      </p>
      
    </div>
    <div id="refer">

    </div>
    <p align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hidden-div').hide();
  $("#select_btn").change(function() {
    toggleFields();
  });

});

function toggleFields() {
  var selectVal = $("#select_btn").val();
  if (selectVal <= 5) {
    $hiddenHtml = $('#hidden-div').clone().html();
    $("#refer").html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectVal; i++) {
      $("#refer").append($hiddenHtml);
    }
  }
}
/*$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  console.log( $( this ).serializeArray() );
  event.preventDefault();
});*/

</script>


</head>
  <?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($name); ++$i) {
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if($link === false){
     die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 // Attempt insert query execution
 $sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (name,email,mobile) VALUES ('$name[0]','$email[$i]', '$mobile[$i]')";
 echo "$sql";
 if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
     echo "Records added successfully.";
 } else{
     echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
 } 

 // Close connection
 mysqli_close($link);
 }
?>
```

Here i attached working code for reference of any one

Comment: how to store the value based on the selection. if option is 2 i am showing two times of the form fields. How to pass it

Comment: first read the above the kink what i have to post it. then TRYYYYY fianly ask your doubts. the link provide all things

Comment: i create the database connection...How to insert the array value in the table

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013211/how-to-insert-array-of-data-into-mysql-using-php

Comment: print_r($_POST[name]);

$count = count($_POST[name]);
print_r($count );

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
{
$sql = "insert into test1 (name,email,mobile) values ('$_POST[name][$i]','$_POST[email][$i]','$_POST[mobile][$i]')";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
} i tried this  it shows the following error insert into test1 (name,email,mobile) values ('Array[0]','Array[0]','Array[0]')
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\validate.php on line 23

Comment: @sakthi i update my ans . just copy and past it. just change the connection and table name, column name.. its working perfectly . if its help to you accept my ans and upvote me

Comment: hiArray ( [referer_name] => rfgdgd [referer_mobile] => 9875885858525 [referer_email] => ffffff [name] => Array ( [0] => [1] => dfddsf ) [mobile] => Array ( [0] => [1] => tghgfhggfh ) [email] => Array ( [0] => [1] => fgfdgfdgdfg ) ) when print the output. How to store the value in table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599422/how-to-insert-array-value-into-mysql-database

Comment: my result is contain like Array ( [referer_name] => rfgdgd [referer_mobile] => 9875885858525 [referer_email] => ffffff [name] => Array ( [0] => [1] => dfddsf ) [mobile] => Array ( [0] => [1] => tghgfhggfh ) [email] => Array ( [0] => [1] => fgfdgfdgdfg ) )

Comment: i dont know thats y i put here

Comment: i want to check the duplication entry of mobile no. how can i do this

Comment: post new question