# Code rewrite for: insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is in reference to the post made here: [insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql)

My question is, can anyone explain this in more detail? I dont understand what `$data` and what `$row` is or does.

I'm pulling in many variables from a form like: `$Customer = $_POST['Customer'];` So if someone can show an example of how to use this code with multiple variables, it would be real nice.

```
$sql = array(); 
foreach( $data as $row ) 
{
    $sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['text']).'", '.$row['category_id'].')';
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (text, category) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

Answer (score 1):

from: [PHP: foreach - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.

In this code, `$data` is an array. On each iteration, foreach will assign the value of the current row to `$row`. This is equivalent to:

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data);$i++)
{
    $row = $data[$i];
    //use $row however u want
}
```

For example:

```
$data[0]['text'] = 'text for category1';
$data[0]['category_id'] = '1';

$data[1]['text'] = 'text for category2';
$data[1]['category_id'] = '2';

$data[2]['text'] = 'text for category3';
$data[2]['category_id'] = '3';
```

After running your foreach using this `$data` variable, if you use `var_dump($row)`, you will get something like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(25) "("text for category1", 1)"
  [1] =>
  string(25) "("text for category2", 2)"
  [2] =>
  string(25) "("text for category3", 3)"
}
```

The last line will [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) this array to create a valid mysql query.

PS: By the way, mysql extension is deprecated. You should learn [mysqli - mysql improved](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [mysql pdo - php data objects](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)