# Why is my INSERT INTO for multiple inputs not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I'm trying to put multiple records in my database using php and mysql.  I'm able to do the first INSERT if I don't try also doing the second one. Once I add the second insert, no record is written at all.  I'm think that it is a syntax error but I tried very clear examples from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp and [insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql) but still not working.  The only difference is the concatination and the semi-colins at the end of the statement.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

```
 $query="INSERT INTO  myTable (
 `user1` ,
 `user2` ,
 `user3` 
 )
 VALUES ('data1', 'data2' , 'data3');";

   $query .="INSERT INTO  myTable (
 `user1` ,
 `user2` ,
 `user3` 
 )
 VALUES ('data4', 'data5' , 'data6')";
```

Comment: that first w3schools example is why we generally say not to use w3schools, it has some terrible code. the 2nd link has a great example, but you completely ignoring it.

Comment: I tried the example from the second link.  I did not ignore it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't write separate queries and append them together (unless you're using mysqli_multi_query which those links suggest you are not doing and that would be inefficient anyway). You only need a comma separated list of values to be inserted once you have constructed your INSERT statement:

```
// Removed semi-colon terminating the query
$query="INSERT INTO  myTable (
 `user1` ,
 `user2` ,
 `user3` 
 )
 VALUES ('data1', 'data2' , 'data3')";

// removed insert statement, added required leading comma
$query .=",('data4', 'data5' , 'data6')";
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!  Appreciate your help.