# Load data from JSON file to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to store two fields from the JSON data found [here](https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/YAHOO/INDEX_VIX.json) in a mysql database. First I create PHP arrays for the data I want using:

```
$o = file_get_contents("vixData.json");
$o = json_decode($o);
$date = []; 
$close = []; 
$set = $o->dataset->data;
foreach($set as $pos)
{
array_push($date,$pos[0]);
array_push($close,$pos[4]);
}
```

Works fine. Now I am trying to adapt [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql) question on inserting multiple rows via a php array. First I implode my arrays:

```
$date = implode(",", $date);
$close = implode(",", $close);
```

Then try to insert to the db using:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO vix (date,close) VALUES (".$date.",".$close.")";

    if (mysqli_multi_query($dbc, $sql)) {
        echo "VIX Load Successful";
    } else {
        echo "VIX Load Error";
    }
```

I'm seeing my load error. There is no database connection issue because $dbc is used earlier in my script. Trying to debug; is my SQL INSERT statement valid? Can anyone see the issue?

Kind regards,

Comment: remove . operator beside variable in query

Comment: should work with or without the . operator right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

1. As mentioned other mate you need to use quotes for Date string.
2. Second you can not use `mysqli_multi_query()` as like that.

**Modified Code:**

You can use multiple `INSERT` Statement as like that:

```
$o = file_get_contents("vixData.json");
$o = json_decode($o);
$date = []; 
$close = []; 
$set = $o->dataset->data;
foreach($set as $pos)
{
    array_push($date,$pos[0]);
    array_push($close,$pos[4]);
}

$sql = "";
foreach ($date as $key => $value) {
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO vix (date,close) VALUES ('".$value."','".$close[$key]."'); ";
}

if (mysqli_multi_query($dbc, $sql)) {
    echo "VIX Load Successful";
} else {
    echo "VIX Load Error";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at it quickly, it seems your values are not wrapped in quotes in your SQL. Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vix (date,close) VALUES ('".$date."','".$close."')";
```

Removing the concat operator (.) will result in the same.

Comment: Awesome! It's worth noting that if $date or $close have an apostrophe, your query will probably break too. Make sure to escape your input.

Comment: @Marinus: you missed the multi query.. but nice answer... earn my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes and concatinator wrapping your Values.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vix (date,close) VALUES ('$date','$close')";
```