# how to optimize this sql insertion php code?

Tags: php, mysql, rdbms

I have mysql database and I want to insert about 40'000 rows into it from PHP code , but my code takes more than 15 minutes to insert the rows, **is there any chances to optimize it?** where is my problem(PHP code / database design) ?

here are the details:

**- the row data** are stored in a utf-8 txt file the values separated by "\t" tab character and every row sets in one line of the file, like this

string view:

```
"value1\tvalue2\tvalue3\value4\value5\r\nvalue1\tvalue2\tvalue3\value4\value5\r\nvalue1\tvalue2\tvalue3\value4\value5\r\nvalue1\tvalue2\tvalue3\value4\value5\r\n"
```

text reader view:

```
value1     value2     value3     value4     value5
value1     value2     value3     value4     value5
value1     value2     value3     value4     value5
value1     value2     value3     value4     value5
```

**-the data base** has 3 tables as this:

```
table1 countries fields(1) (NAME varchar -primarykey-)
table2 products fields(2) (HS varchar - primarykey-, NAME varchar) 
table3 imports fields (6) (product_hs varchar -foreignkey->products(HS),
counteryname varchar - foreignkey->countries (NAME),
year year,
units int,
weight int,
value int)
```

**- php code** was like this

```
$conn = new mysqli($hn,$un,$pw,$db);
if($conn->connect_error) {die($conn->connect_error);}

$x = 0; // row counter
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);

while(!feof($filehandle)){
$x++;
echo $x . ":  ";
$fileline = fgets($filehandle);
$fields = explode("\t", $fileline);
$query = "INSERT INTO imports(product_hs,counteryname,year,units,weight,value) VALUES(" . "'" . $fields[0] ."','". $fields[1] . "','2014','". $fields[2] . "','" . $fields[3] . "','" . $fields[4] .  "');";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if(!$result) {
    echo $conn->error . "</br>";
}else{
    echo $result . "</br>";
}
};
```

first I thought it is an index problem that slows down the insertion , so I removed all the indexes from "imports" table , but it didn't go faster!!
is the problem from the database design or from my php code?

*also note that the browser is notifying "waiting for response from the server" for the first 5 minutes then most of the remaining time is notifying  "transferring data from server", is this because the response html has more than 40'000 line for the row counter`1:1 </br> 2:1 </br> .....`(declared in the php code)?*

please consider I'm very newbie, thanks.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put arbitrary user data directly into a query, it always requires escaping.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/780045/752527

Comment: If you have well-formatted data, why not use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)?

Comment: Re: the "row counter output". Why not just comment those lines out and find out?

Comment: The `load data` operation might be a good idea but I just wanted to point out that using prepared statements goes significantly faster as the query is only analyzed once and then records can be inserted extremely fast.

Comment: +1 for `Load data infile`. Estimate: 2 to some seconds. You should try it, even if your file is not in the correct format, it might be faster to read the file into php and write a new, formatted file and use this for load data (it might be a good idea to do that anyway to check for errors or something). With prepared statements you might get to similar speeds though.

Comment: @tadman yes this function boosted the time amazingly! as you see in the tests results in the answer , thank you very much, and thank you also for the resources on the sql injection bug :)

Comment: @Solarflare yes, exactly 5 seconds it is as you estimated , I shared the tests result in an answer , thank you

Comment: @Uueerdo unfortunately , it wasn't response html problem , it was a bad php code problem that makes a separate query for every line of the data, i tried your suggestion but it just delayed the response to the end of php script since there was no `echos` in the loop, thank you.

Comment: @HanletEscaño yes it did help a lot , especially the part of gathering all statements into 1 insert statement, although  I didn't try it because  `LOAD DATA INFILE` did the job , but i will give it a try later, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) and [Hanlet Escaño](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752527/hanlet-esca%C3%B1o) and [Uueerdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4104224/uueerdo) and [Julie Pelletier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5207302/julie-pelletier) and [Solarflare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6248528/solarflare)
for helping me in the comments.

I did 3 different changes in my PHP code using the approaches you suggested in the comments, then I tested the results and here are the tests results.

**The conclusion of the 3 tests:** as tadman suggested, the key is in [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) . it dramatically reduced the execution time to less than 7 seconds, and these are the 3 tests.

---

**ORIGINAL CODE:** ~ 26 minutes

[image]

---

**TEST 1 :** ~ 34 minutes

[image]

(as [Uueerdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4104224/uueerdo) suggested I removed the `echo` statements and the rows counter from the loop)

```
while(!feof($filehandle)){
// $x++; // commented out
//echo $x . ":  "; // commented out
$fileline = fgets($filehandle);
$fields = explode("\t", $fileline);
$query = "INSERT INTO products(hs,arabicname,englishname) VALUES(" . "'" . str_replace("'", ".", $fields[0]) ."'," . "'". str_replace("'", ".", $fields[1]) . "'," . "'". str_replace("'", ".", $fields[2]) . "');"; 
$result = $conn->query($query); 
/* // commented out
if(!$result) {echo  $conn->error . "</br>";}
}else{echo $result . "</br>";}
*/};
```

---

**TEST 2 :** ~ 7 seconds

[image]

(As [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman) said I searched for [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) and it was super powerful

```
//replace the entire loop with this simple query
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'" . 
addslashes("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bots\\impandexp\\imports.txt")
. "' INTO TABLE imports FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY
'\r\n'(product_hs,counteryname,units,weight,value) SET  year = '2014';";
 $result = $conn->query($query);
```

---

**TEST 3 :** ~ 5 seconds

[image]

It was the same as test 2 except that I found useful tips on the same page that tadman give, that help in maximizing the speed for.

[Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)

```
// turning off index checks that might slows down bulk data insertion
$query = "SET foreign_key_checks=0;";
$conn->query($query);
$query = "SET unique_checks=0;";
$conn->query($query);
$query ="SET autocommit=0;";
$conn->query($query);

$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'" . addslashes("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bots\\impandexp\\imports.txt") . "' INTO TABLE imports FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'(product_hs,counteryname,units,weight,value) SET  year = '2014';";
$result = $conn->query($query);
echo $result . "</br>";
// turning them on again
$query = "SET foreign_key_checks=1;";
$conn->query($query);
$query = "SET unique_checks=1;";
$conn->query($query);
$query ="COMMIT;";
$conn->query($query);
```

Comment: Good work on getting it running. Just remember that `addslashes` is not the right tool for this job and `bind_param` is. This difference might seem academic, but it's an important distinction because one is a very superficial treatment of the string that leaves you exposed to SQL injection problems, the other can handle any kind of data you throw at it. Parameterized queries solve a lot of nasty debugging problems, too, since your data and query are kept separated.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that most MySQL servers run with default InnoDB settings. Not only can you increase the [size of the buffer pool using `innodb_buffer_pool_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) but you can also use other [performance tricks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) if it's necessary.

Comment: @tadman I used `addslashes()` because I couldn't add any slashes without it, I was getting the error can't find the file `C:xampphtdocsbotsimpandexpimports.txt` , why php removed all the slashes? is there any way else to add the slashes rather than `addslashes()` ?, thanks

Comment: Try doing `LODA DATA IN LOCAL INFILE ? INTO TABLE ...`, then use `prepare`, `bind_param` and `execute`. That leads to predictable, consistent results.