# How to insert array result into mysql using prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I use to insert records into mysql using prepared statement,for non-array value the below code is fine but for the array types posted it gives me the error:

> Array to string conversion

index.php

```
<input type="text" name="test[]" /> 
<input type="text" name="test1[]" />
```

OUT PUT

```
 [test] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [test1] => Array ( [0] => 2 )
```

PHP insert  ( the posted data is in array )

```
$test=array_map('trim',$_POST["test"]);
$test1=array_map('trim',$_POST["test1"]);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test(v1,v2) VALUES (?,?)");
stmt->bind_param("ss",$test,$test1)
stmt->execute();
```

Now,please help how to insert array data posted html forms using prepared statement into mysql. later I need to record multiple rows using prepared statement. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql)

Comment: you can't bind an array to parameter ...

Comment: freyBake please let me know how do then?

Comment: foreach loop -> using value as the parameter bound

Comment: Leg Nurutdinov, I search alot but could not find the exact solution for my case, please put your answer if possible. thanks

Comment: treyBake, could u please provide me an example?

Comment: Can you provide us with an output of `$test` and `$test1` arrays?

Comment: Your `<input>` is called `test2[]` but in your PHP code you use `$_POST['test1']`?

Comment: Cobra_Fast i change the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$test=array_map('trim',$_POST["test"]);
$test1=array_map('trim',$_POST["test1"]);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test(v1,v2) VALUES (?,?)");
$error=false;
foreach($test AS $key=>$value){
    if(! stmt->execute([$value,$test1[$key]])){
       $error=true;  
       break;
    }
}
if($error) // handle error
```

Running queries in loops like this is what prepared statements are for.

Comment: Thanks antG, its exactly what I need.