# PHP Mysql Insert Batch if not exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have searched that there is already a way in inserting avoiding the duplicate error

ref: [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

```
INSERT INTO table_listnames (name, address, tele)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Unknown' AS name, 'Unknown' AS address, '022' AS tele) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM table_listnames WHERE name = 'Unknown'
) LIMIT 1;

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM `table_listnames`;

+----+---------+-----------+------+
| id | name    | address   | tele |
+----+---------+-----------+------+
|  1 | Rupert  | Somewhere | 022  |
|  2 | John    | Doe       | 022  |
|  3 | Unknown | Unknown   | 022  |
+----+---------+-----------+------+
```

is there a way for this to do in batch?
or how is the format in adding data as a batch

ref: [insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql)

Planning to integrate this one

```
$sql = array(); 
foreach( $data as $row ) {
    $sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['text']).'", '.$row['category_id'].')';
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (text, category) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

is there a way?

Comment: Can you use INSERT IGNORE? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax for this. This will simplify the query, and allow the use of the `VALUES()` statement, which is handy to pass parameters from your application.

For this to work, you need a unique (or primary key) constraint on colum `name`. Create it if it does not exist:

```
create unique index idx_table_listnames on table_listnames(name);
```

Then, you can do:

```
insert into table_listnames(name, address, tele)
values('Unknown', 'Unknown', '022')
on duplicate key update name = values(name)
```

The conflict clause traps violations on the unique index, and performs a no-op update.

Side note: use parameterized queries to pass data from your application to the query; escaping input is not enough to make your query safe.

Comment: thanks this might do the job. answer accepted. but if is there a way to do the following in batch that would be perfect.